# execute code in java fields

Tags: java, variables, static, field

I'm in a position where I have referenced a static field variable to a custom class. I need to make alterations to the variable with methods from the class it references. I can not instantiate the class under construction. Simplified example:

```
public class House {
  private static MaterialsRequired matsReq = new MaterialsRequired();
  private String size;

  private House(String size) {
    this.size = size;
  }

  public static MaterialsRequired getMaterialsRequired() {

  }

  public static void Build(String size) {
    new House(size); //Do I need to put 'this(size)' here?
    //some code here to expend the materials required factored based on size.
  }
```

To construct the house I need to know the materials required (for standard size). To know the materials required I need to call the addMaterial() method of MaterialsRequired. What do I do?

EDIT: I need to call the addMaterial() method repeatedly on matsReq. Maybe ten times. When I call House.build() I want the matsReq to have been altered by method calls (if my question was unspecific). Also it doesn't satisfy me to just set the materials required every time the build()  or getMaterialsRequired() methods are called.

The question have been answered! Solution:

```
  private static MaterialsRequired matsReq = new MaterialsRequired();
  static {
    matsReq.addMaterial(mat1);
    matsReq.addMaterial(mat2);
    matsReq.addMaterial(mat3);
  }
  private String size;
```

Comment: Homework? And basically there is no question in your "question". So my best advice about what do you do, would be to formulate a better question or figure out your homework alone.

Comment: I do not understand. It really seems to be clear what my problem is to me. Can you maybe try to explain what the unclear part is??

Comment: If you could explain What you want to do clearly. It is vague as it stands

Answer (score 0):

Having a build method doesn't work, because it is just another constructor. It's what happens when you make an instance. I'm guessing, if anything, you build to be outside of the class. It would be something that called the constructor and did a couple other things.

What you probably want is, outside of the class, a method that creates an instance of a house (using the constructor) and then some code to "use up" the materials needed to make the house from a structure that holds the materials (again, outside of the class).

Since you seem to want to make houses with different material requirements, why don't you make subclasses of the most basic house (or better yet, an abstract class, maybe called "dwelling") that have a different required materials list.

Comment: House is already a superclass that has just been presented as a specific house for simplification. I can see your point that the build method is abundant, but it is not really relevant. My problem is that I need to know the materials required to build a house from a static class call:

House.materialsRequired(). MaterialsRequired is an extensive ArrayList containing a whole other system of classes. It is defaulted to contain 0 units of all material. Every subclass of House requires different materials that will be determined with for instance MaterialsRequired.addStone(50).

Comment: If you can see I want to assign a seperate 'MaterialsRequired' class to each type of House. I need to know the MaterialsRequired for each type of house before construction, and my intention was to store that information within the specific house-subclasses themselves. Since my question haven't gotten a very clear response this leads me to suspect that it may not be possible at all :S

Comment: Add the materials to the `public static MaterialsRequired` at the top, outside of a method. This assumes that for the subclass, all houses have the same materials required. But that's how the class must be structured for it to ever be available statically.

Comment: Also, I'd change MaterialsRequired to something like MaterialsList, because then you can make it easier on yourself if you have a MaterialsList which has all your available resources and you can save yourself a lot of effort by making a remove method that takes another MaterialsList (`House.matsReq`) and subtracts those parts from it.

Comment: "Add the materials to the public static MaterialsRequired at the top, outside of a method." That right there is my question is exactly!! What does this mean, how do I do it?

Comment: Your other answer was removed. I had commented on it something that may help the confusion. In your example the solution would simply be: private static ArrayList<String> matsReq = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("mat1", "mat2", "mat3"));

Comment: Yeah, it was unfixable code. I just made a new answer. We can move down to there if it's not what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

Doing some guesswork...

```
public class StandardHouse{
  public static MaterialsList MATERIALS_REQUIRED = new MaterialsList();
  MATERIALS_REQUIRED.add("material", numMats);
  ...

  public StandardHouse() {
    //probably don't need anything here
  }
}
```

Then later

```
MaterialsList matsYouHave = ...;
StandardHouse house1 = new StandardHouse();
matsYouHave.remove(StandardHouse.MATERIALS_REQUIRED);
```

Comment: Ben, I thank you SO much for your time and patience. I have my answer now based on research from this little sentence of yours: "write your code outside method".
Basically all I was looking was the concept of "static blocks" :)

Comment: I have edited the solution into my question if you're unclear what I ever wanted to achieve ^.^

Comment: I should have thought to say "static blocks." Whoops. But hey, I've only been doing Java a few weeks. But that's why I do this at all: I'm trying to solidify my own understanding. So you've helped me, too. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Try making them in two classes

```
public class House {

  private List<String> materialList = new ArrayList<String>();
  private House(List<String> materialList ) {
    this.materialList = materialList ;
  }



  public void Build() {
    MaterialsRequired matsReq = new MaterialsRequired();
    materialList .add(matsReq.setMaterialsRequired("material1"));
    materialList .add(matsReq.setMaterialsRequired("material2"));
    materialList .add(matsReq.setMaterialsRequired("material3"));
    //some code here to expend the materials required factored based on size.
  }
```

And then

```
class MaterialRequired
 {
    private String materialsRequired;

    public String setMaterialsRequired(String material) {
        materialRequired = material;
        return materialRequired;
  }
```

Comment: This doesn't work at all. House.add(...) isn't defined, materialsRequired should be a list not a string, you're never constructing an instance of a house, yet nothing's static, etc.